# Linking to another .cshtml

Tags: razor, hyperlink, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to link to Login.cshtml page from Home.cshtml and it can't seem to find the link.

Home.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Shared/Master.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}


    @section menu 
    {
        <a href="/Login">Login</a>
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        //
        // GET: /Home/Home

        public ActionResult Home()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Login

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }



    }
```

RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Home" }
        );
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Login Page would be at /Home/Login

if you are wanting a page for /Login you need to create a new controller called LoginController with an action result method of Index.

You need to have this to serve the pages in your RouteConfig:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Home" }
        );
```

This should also sort out your default home page

Comment: It can't seem to find /Home/Login either

Comment: Have you built the solution since adding the ActionResult Login?  iof so try using HTML.ActionLink to build your link

Comment: You mean the ActionResult Login in my current HomeController?

Comment: Have you messed around with the RouteConfig file then as that that should mean /Home/Login should work, what error are you getting?

Comment: I have, I added my RouteConfig in my main post. If that is incorrect, how do I get Home.cshtml as the homepage?

Comment: @KingCronus Yes, I mentioned that in previous comments.

Comment: @Pete Thankyou, that worked although I also had to add '..' before '/Home/Login'

Comment: @Neeta, apologies, I missed that.